# add a dark mode on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

i try to put a dark mode with jquery but he do not work i need some help.  i want the put the dark mode on click for the id #btntheme but he do not work , i want to be able to switch to colorful theme on click
anybody have an id on how to do it ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:">
    <div class="two columns absolute" style="background: ">
      <a href="home.php"> <img src="../content/logo_tw.png" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"></a><br>
      <a href="home.php"> <img src="../content/home.png" width="20" height="20" alt="home"><strong>Home</strong></a><br>
      <a href="recherche.php"> <img src="../content/loupe.jpg" width="20" height="20"
          alt="recherche"><strong>Search</strong></a><br>
      <a href="messages.php"> <img src="../content/message.png" width="20" height="20"
          alt="messages"><strong>Messages</strong></a><br>
      <a href="profile.php"> <img src="../content/profile.png" width="20" height="20"
          alt="profile"><strong>Profile</strong></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="ten columns separator border" style="background: ">
      <div class="pseudo">
        <a href="profile.php">
          <h3>Risitas</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
      <hr>
      <div id="fond"></div>
      <div id="avatar">
        <img src="../content/risitasb.jpg">
        <a href="modif_profil.php">  <button id="btnfollow" class="button-primary">Edit profile</button></a>
      </div>
      <form action="profile.php" method="post">
        <button id="btntheme" type="submit" class="button-primary">Theme</button>
        <button id="btncommentaire" class="button-primary">Comments</button>
        <button id="btnretweet" class="button-primary">Retweet</button>
      </form>

  </div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. can you share full code

Comment: my css want load on there

Answer (score 0):

I made you a codepen:
https://codepen.io/billgil/pen/WNvoGjB

I added the JavaScript needed into the HTML to keep things simple for you. When you click the button 'dark-mode' class is added to the body tag. Then use the CSS example provided to restyle anything inside that class.

Enjoy!

```
<!-- MY NEW BUTTON TO TOGGLE DARK MODE -->
<button id='jsDarkToggle' onclick={document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode')}>Dark Mode</button>

<!-- YOUR HTML IN YOUR EXAMPLE -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:">
    <div class="two columns absolute" style="background: ">
      <a href="home.php"> <img src="../content/logo_tw.png" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"></a><br>
      <a href="home.php"> <img src="../content/home.png" width="20" height="20" alt="home"><strong>Home</strong></a><br>
      <a href="recherche.php"> <img src="../content/loupe.jpg" width="20" height="20"
          alt="recherche"><strong>Search</strong></a><br>
      <a href="messages.php"> <img src="../content/message.png" width="20" height="20"
          alt="messages"><strong>Messages</strong></a><br>
      <a href="profile.php"> <img src="../content/profile.png" width="20" height="20"
          alt="profile"><strong>Profile</strong></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="ten columns separator border" style="background: ">
      <div class="pseudo">
        <a href="profile.php">
          <h3>Risitas</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
      <hr>
      <div id="fond"></div>
      <div id="avatar">
        <img src="../content/risitasb.jpg">
        <a href="modif_profil.php">  <button id="btnfollow" class="button-primary">Edit profile</button></a>
      </div>
      <form action="profile.php" method="post">
        <button id="btntheme" type="submit" class="button-primary">Theme</button>
        <button id="btncommentaire" class="button-primary">Comments</button>
        <button id="btnretweet" class="button-primary">Retweet</button>
      </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
.dark-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode a {
  color: white;
}
```